# How to set a search scope in SPServices search function?

Tags: search, jquery, caml-query, spservices, search-scope

I am doing a search using this code:

```
var queryText;
queryText = "<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>";
queryText += "<Query>";
queryText += "<SupportedFormats>";
queryText += "<Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document</Format>";
queryText += "</SupportedFormats>";
queryText += "<Context>";
queryText += "<QueryText language='en-US' type='STRING'>";
queryText += text;
queryText += "</QueryText>";
queryText += "</Context>";
queryText += "<Range><Count>1000</Count></Range>";
queryText += "<Properties>";
queryText += "<Property name='Title'></Property>";
queryText += "<Property name='Path'></Property>";
queryText += "<Property name='Description'></Property>";
queryText += "<Property name='Write'></Property>";
queryText += "<Property name='Rank'></Property>";
queryText += "<Property name='Size'></Property>";
queryText += "</Properties>";
//queryText += "<SortByProperties>";
//queryText += "<SortProperty name='Title' direction='ascending' order="1"></SortProperty>";
//queryText += "</SortByProperties>";
queryText += "<EnableSpellCheck>false</EnableSpellCheck>";
queryText += "<TrimDuplicates>false</TrimDuplicates>";
queryText += "<IncludeRelevantResults>false</IncludeRelevantResults>";
queryText += "</Query>";
queryText += "</QueryPacket>";


$().SPServices({
    operation: "Query",
    queryXml: queryText,
    completefunc: searchComplete
});
```

However, I want to set the search scope to a specific library. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piecing together 2 articles ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms543175%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [2](http://www.sharepoint-answers.com/microsoft/SharePoint-Design/30212417/sharepoint-search.aspx)), it looks as if your QueryText section should be like this:

```
<QueryText language=xml:lang type='MSSQLFT'>
SELECT Title,shortdescription,description,Rank, FROM portal..scope() WHERE
CONTAINS ('"test*"')   AND  ( ("SCOPE" = 'TestScope') )  ORDER BY "Rank" DESC
</QueryText>
```

I had looked into this before, but we ripped the functionality out of the site. [Anita](http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/tag/spservices/) has some useful posts on the search web service and SPServices.

Comment: I got it working with the solution here
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/120c875a-5240-45cc-a587-c6e376872315